# Writing and reading a new file by passing the files as an argument to a function in a python script

Tags: python, file, function, cmd, os.path

I have a python script that gets input file names from the command prompt. I created a list to store all the input files and pass that to a function to create a new file with all the input files merged at once. Now, I pass this newly written file as an input to another function. I am getting an error message

**TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found**

Code:

```
file_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
for arg in range(1,len(sys.argv)-2):    
    file_list.append(sys.argv[arg])
    process_name = sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]
integrate_files(file_list,process_name)

def integrate_files(file_list,process_name):
    with open('result.log', 'w' ) as result:        
       for file_ in file_list:
          for line in open( file_, 'r' ):
             result.write( line )
    start_process(result,process_name)

def start_process(result,process_name):
    with open(result,'r') as mainFile:
       content = mainFile.readlines()
```

I am getting this error highlighted at the lines having the word **with.open()**. I tried to print the abspath of the result.log file.  It printed **closed file 'result.log', mode 'w' at 0x000000000227578**. Where am I going wrong ? How should I create a new file and pass it to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `result` is a closed file object:

```
start_process(result,process_name)
```

I think you want

```
start_process('result.log', process_name)
```

You could clean the script up a bit with

```
import shutil
                                                                                            file_list = sys.argv[1:-1]
process_name = sys.argv[-1]
integrate_files(file_list,process_name)

def integrate_files(file_list,process_name):
    with open('result.log', 'w' ) as result:        
       for file_ in file_list:
           with open(file_) as infile:
               shutil.copyfileobj(infile, result)
    start_process('result.log',process_name)

def start_process(result,process_name):
    with open(result,'r') as mainFile:
       content = mainFile.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
with open('result.log', 'w' ) as result:        
   # ...
start_process(result,process_name)
```

Since you reopen your file in `start_process`, you should just pass the name:

```
start_process(result.name, process_name)
```

Or just be explicit:

```
start_process('result.log', process_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `with open('result.log', 'w') as result:`, you make `result` be an *object representing the actual file on disk*. That is different from the *name* of the file.

You certainly can pass that `result` to another function. But since it will be the actual file object, and not a file name, you can't pass that to `open` - `open` expects a name of a file, and looks for the file with that name, in order to *create a new* file object.

You can call methods on that file object, but none of them will actually re-open the file. Instead, the simplest thing is to *remember and pass the file name*, so that `start_process` can `open` it again.

As shown in @matsjoyce's answer, the file object remembers the original file name. So you *could* pass the object, and have `start_process` get the name. But that's messy. Really, just pass the name. (You could, like mats showed, pass `result.name` explicitly instead of making your own `name` variable first). Passing file objects around is usually not what you want - do it only when you want to split the reading/writing work across functions (and have a good reason for that).

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
with open('result.log', 'w' ) as result:
```

When you define `result` above, you are only defining it for that single loop, so it won't pass when you call `start_process`

So either change `start_process` to:

```
with open('result.log','r') as mainFile:
```

Or you could pass the string `result.log` into `start_process`  instead of the variable `result`:

```
file_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
for arg in range(1,len(sys.argv)-2):    
    file_list.append(sys.argv[arg])
    process_name = sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]
integrate_files(file_list,process_name)

def integrate_files(file_list,process_name):
    with open('result.log', 'w' ) as result:        
       for file_ in file_list:
          for line in open( file_, 'r' ):
             result.write( line )
    start_process('result.log',process_name)

def start_process(result,process_name):
    with open(result,'r') as mainFile:
       content = mainFile.readlines()
```